# Config-based authentication in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 web page that is, for the most part, accessed without authentication. There is a single page that I want to protect for admin-only access (ELMAH's error log, specifically). Since I only require a single admin login, I'd like to avoid the complexity of maintaining a user/password database.

I've done some research, and I've found that previous versions of ASP.NET provide the ability to use Forms Authentication with a password encrypted in the web.config:

```
<forms loginUrl="Admin" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
  <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
    <user name="admin" password="encryptedPassword" />
  </credentials>
</forms>
```

Then, the authentication controller uses `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` and `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` to validate entered credentials. However, I'm hesitant to use this solution because:

1. The `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` API is now [obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx).
2. `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` will redirect the user directly, rather than returning a `RedirectResult`. This doesn't follow the MVC controller pipeline, and so things like unit testing would be more difficult.

Looking through MSDN samples and the default template, it appears that WebMatrix's [`WebSecurity.Login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) API is the new standard for doing Forms Authentication in MVC applications. But, I haven't found a way to use a local (i.e. config-based) authentication provider.

Is there a recommended way to do local authentication, or is this considered a bad practice? What's the simplest method to provide admin authentication without taking on external dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebSecurity.Login` is not "the new standard" for authentication.  It's more like the new "newbie friendly standard".  WebSecurity only really supports SimpleMembership, and that is really simply designed for simple applications.

`FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` has not been a good choice for a long time, so the fact that it's now officially deprecated is not a big deal.

You should probably be using Membership anyways, and use Membership.ValidateUser to validate credentials.  Or, use something like Windows Identity Foundation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll read up more on ASP.NET Membership. What I'm looking for then is a `MembershipProvider` which authenticates from some local source.

Comment: @ScottWegner - not sure what you mean by "local source".  If you mean a local database, then you can certainly use LocalDB or a local SqlServer or Sql Server Express database, and they work fine with SqlMembershipProvider (the old default provider, but still works).

Comment: By "local source", I mean sourced internally from my web project. For example, within the web.config. I won't ever need more than a single login, so I want to avoid managing credentials within a database.